# Pushout of a mono which is not a mono.

Tags: category-theory

I'm studying abelian categories in F. Borceux. I'm trying to solve an exercise : prove that monomorphisms are not stable under pushouts in the category of commutative rings. Any help?

Comment: Given a ring monomorphism $A \to B$ and some ring $C$, the goal is to show that $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} C \to B \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} C$ is not injective for some choice of $A,B,C$

Comment: @leibnewtz That's not how I understand the question. To me the question is more : Find a monomorphism $A\to B$ and a morphism $A\to C$ such that $C\to B\otimes_A C$ is not injective (and this is assuming that we consider unital rings, since otherwise the pushout might be different).

Comment: Me neither... Is my question unclear?

Comment: @Sov Your question is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the counterexample I found with the previous help :

We use the monomorphism $g : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ and the morphism $f : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n$ with $n > 1$. The pushout $g'$ of $g$ will go from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to $\mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_n$, but this last ring is zero and then $g'$ is not a monomorphism.

This question was motivated by the fact that epimorphisms are always stable under pushout. In abelian categories we also have that monomorphisms are stable under pushout, so I wanted to find a counterexample to make it clear that it is not general.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Try using the monomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$.

A stronger hint is hidden below.

> What happens when you push that out along a map $\mathbb{Z}\to C$ where $C$ has torsion?

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your answer I found my counterexample. But I did not understand what you mean by "torsion". Is that  when $C$ has zero divisors ? If so, what happens when you pushout with this $C$ ? Are we going to always have a zero map? How do you prove this?